# python - representing boolean expressions with lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list, boolean

I'm trying to represent boolean expressions in sum of products form(SOP) in Python with only lists.

For example, I have boolean expression

```
ABC+DE(FG+IH)
```

I need to find a list equivalent of the expression above, so by reading the list or nested list and following certain rules to read the list, the program/programmer reading the list will be able to convert it back to the boolean expression.

One way I thought of doing this is constructing nested lists. Two rules to follow:

1. elements in the same list are ANDed together
2. lists are parallel to each other, therfore ORed together.

So for the example above, it will translate to:

```
[[A,B,C],[D,E,[[F,G],[I,H]]]]
```

But this set of rules conflicts itself in some cases. For example, given [[E,F],[D,C]], it can either mean EF+DC or EFDC, as [E,F] and [D,C] are in the same list so they should be anded, but lists are parallel so they should be ORed too.

I feel like I need to set some precedence between the 2 rules above, or add another rule to make it more clear.

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome. Also it's not homework, just something for fun.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might want to accept answers from more of the questions you ask or at least indicate if you have an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could go the LISPy route and have the first item in each list be the operator.  For example, the expression you gave

```
ABC+DE(FG+IH)
```

would become

```
['or', ['and', A, B, C], ['and', D, E, ['or', ['and', F, G], ['and', I, H]]]]
```

Which is pretty readable, considering.  Cheers!

Comment: tuples instead of lists would resemble lisp more closely

Answer (score 5):

Why lists and not trees?

```
OR = 0
AND = 1

class OpNode:
   def __init__(self, op, left, right):
       self.op = op
       self.left = left
       self.right = right

class LeafNode:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
       self.name = name
       self.value = value

A = LeafNode("A", True)
B = LeafNode("B", True)

exp = OpNode(OR, A, OpNode(AND, B, 
                                OpNode(OR, 
                                          LeafNode("C", False), 
                                          LeafNode("D", True))))
```

exp would be the equivalent of `A+B(C+D)`

Comment: I believe it is just a matter of fun!

Comment: This can actually be a good idea. Use a binary tree to represent a boolean expression, all the leaf nodes are the variables, and their parent nodes being the operation

Answer (score 2):

You could have the outermost list mean "OR all direct entries", then swap the meaning of nested lists between OR and AND direct entries. If you count levels of nesting from the outermost being 1 then the terms in odd levels of nesting should be OR'd and the terms in even levels of nesting should be AND'd together.

So `ABC+DE(FG+IH)`

Becomes `[[A,B,C],[D,E,[[F,G],[I,H]]]]`

**Here's some Python code:**

It returns an expression from the list form:

```
def to_bool(lst, depth=0, or_them=True):
    if type(lst) == str:
        return lst
    else:
        partial = ( '+' if or_them else ''
                  ).join( to_bool(x, depth+1, not or_them) for x in lst)
        if or_them and depth > 0:
            # Mixture of variables and sublists so parenthesize
            return '(' + partial + ')'
        else:
            return partial

def main():
    A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I = 'ABCDEFGHI'
    e = [[A,B,C],[D,E,[[F,G],[I,H]]]]
    print('The list form of the boolean expression:', e)
    print('The boolean expression:', to_bool(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Its output:

```
The list form of the boolean expression: [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', [['F', 'G'], ['I', 'H']]]]
The boolean expression: ABC+DE(FG+IH)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can add an additional rule that when the basic elements beside the comma are lists, then they are `ORed` together. Hence, you will not get this conflicted interpretation.

Therefore `[A,B]` has both elements as singletons, so they and `ANDed`, but `[[A,B],[C,D]]` has `ANDs` between singletons and `ORs` between lists, resulting in AB+CD.

In a way, that means that your `rule #2` has precedence over `rule #1`.

Comment: That might solve part of the problem, but it fails when there are both lists and basic variables in the same list. What's [[A,B],C] then?

Comment: [[A,B], C] would be AND, [[A,B], [C]] would be OR.

Comment: But then how would you write (A AND B) AND (C AND D)  ?  Maybe [[A,B], [C,D], True]  ?

Comment: @Luke how do you AND two lists together then? for example express (A+B)(C+D)?

Comment: @Luke just about to ask that. that one is actually what got me stuck

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant. It'd be awkward for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Use lists for AND, tuples for OR.