# Calculating all combinations of nested lists based on logical expression

Tags: python, nested, logical-operators, python-itertools

Let's assume I have a action list, which can contain three different type of actions:

Type A: can contain all types of actions (disjunction)
Type B: can contain all types of actions (**ordered** conjunction)
Type C: cannot contain subactions. This is the level I want to have at the end.

I thought about (based on: [python - representing boolean expressions with lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477977/python-representing-boolean-expressions-with-lists)) that the disjunction and conjunction could be represented by a tuple respectively a list, but I am not sure whether this is an optimal solution.

For type A and B, there is a dict which contains the type elements, e.g.

```
type_a = {
‘a1’: ('b1', 'a2'),
‘a2’: ('c1', 'c2')
}

type_b = {
‘b1’: ['c4', 'c5', 'c7'],
‘b2’:['c3', 'c4']
}
```

**Detailed explanation:**

‘a1’ is equal to `('b1', 'a2')`, which is equal to `(['c4', 'c5','c7'], 'c1', 'c2')`

‘a2’ is equal to `('c1', 'c2')`

‘b1’ is equal to `['c4', 'c5', 'c7']`

‘b2’ is equal to `['c3', 'c4']`

**Example Input:**

```
['a1', 'b2', 'c6']
```

**Expected output:**

The results should only contain type C actions.

*raw*

```
[(['c4', 'c5', 'c7'], 'c1', 'c2'), 'c3', 'c4', 'c6']
```

*all combinations*

```
['c4', 'c5','c7', 'c3', 'c4', 'c6']

['c1', 'c3', 'c4', 'c6']

['c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c6']
```

**Questions:**

- Is the idea with the conjunction and disjunction representation of tuple and lists a good idea?
- What is an efficient way to implement this?
- Is there a possibility to implement the function, which calculates
  all combinations, with the itertools? (I am not really familiar with
  them, but I've heard that they are very powerful)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, itertools isn't of much help here. The following recursive beast seems to do the job however:

```
def combinations(actions):
    if len(actions)==1:
        action= actions[0]
        try:
            actions= type_a[action]
        except KeyError:
            try:
                actions= type_b[action]
            except KeyError:
                #action is of type C, the only possible combination is itself
                yield actions
            else:
                #action is of type B (conjunction), combine all the actions
                for combination in combinations(actions):
                    yield combination
        else:
            #action is of type A (disjunction), generate combinations for each action
            for action in actions:
                for combination in combinations([action]):
                    yield combination
    else:
        #generate combinations for the first action in the list
        #and combine them with the combinations for the rest of the list
        action= actions[0]
        for combination in combinations(actions[1:]):
            for combo in combinations([action]):
                yield combo + combination
```

The idea is to generate all possible values for the first action (`'a1'`) and combine them with the (recursively generated) combinations of the remaining actions (`['b2', 'c6']`).

This also eliminates the need to represent conjunction and disjunction with lists and tuples, which, to be honest, I found rather confusing.

Comment: Excellent, thanks man. As an extension I thought about to accept also list elements, which contains the mentioned string as the first element e.g.
`[['a1', {'param': 'something'}], ['b2', {'param': 'something'}]`. The second element (the dict) should be passed.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [set type](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) in Python which support set operations - if you do not care about ordering.